# CSS issue, when filling in a form the header goes up

Tags: css, header, positioning

I have a strange CSS issue, I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

When I press the "Sign In" button on my website and I start to type in the Username, the header goes up. I really don't know what is causing this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Here is some code:

The form:

```
.tooltip-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  display:none;
}

.tooltip-wrap .corner {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    margin-left:-5px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#fff;
}

.tooltip-text { 
    float:left;
    margin-left:-50%;
    padding:1em 15px;
    background:#fff;
    color:#333;
}
```

This is the part that goes up:

```
.header-navigation.back {
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:-6px;
    border:none;
display:block; height:137px; width:1171px; padding:0px; outline:none; text-indent:-9999px;
background-image:url('xhttp://frenchegg.com/images/backmenu.png');
}
```

You need to click on Username and start typing something.

Comment: Hm. What browser are you using? I can't seem to replicate the problem in Firefox 20.0.1/Win7

Comment: @DaiYoukai Make sure you click on username - I thought the same thing

Comment: @Louis - You should *seriously* consider a more responsive design ...

Comment: Nothing happens when you click on sign in in safari on ipad

Comment: Yeah, just not seeing the actual problem - Tested in IE9/Win7 as well

Comment: You need to click on Username and start typing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is along these lines:

Set `.header-wrap` to have `overflow:visible` (well, remove overflow hidden!) - this will mean you have to slice those character graphics to have flat bottoms.

Then, change `.tooltip-wrap` to be `position:absolute;z-index:2;` (not fixed).

I also noticed that you have the placeholder polyfill in your head. This means you could use that attribute on the input rather than value; like so:

`<input type="text" name="user_login" placeholder="Username">`

Very cute site!

Comment: Thank you! However I'd rather keep the characters hidden by the main content (overflow) since my website is responsive, on some devices they will be shown completely.

Comment: I still think this is your starting point - from here you have options: z-index the banner over the bottom of the eggs, wrap the eggs in `overflow:hidden;` wrappers, etc. The above solution takes care of the "flow" of where your tooltip menu is. The rest is aesthetics.

Comment: The banner where it says "as easy as 123" disappears when people sign in to the website. Therefore it wouldn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `line-height` of the input box - fixes the issue.

HTML to change:

```
<input type="text" id="text-user" name="user_login" value="Username" style="
    line-height: 15px;
">
```

CSS:

```
#text-user{
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

The reason is because the line-height of the input was much smaller without text, than it was with text. So when you typed something into the box, the `line-height` expanded which is what caused the header to be pushed up.

**Edit**

I see you're having no luck with the code, so do these two more things and you're sure to be up and running - it's working here for me.

Remove the following from `.site-header`:

```
padding: 2em 0;
```

Next, change the `row` style to look like this:

```
.row{ 
margin: 0 auto; 
padding: 0 30px; 
width: 1171px; 
height: 137px; 
}
```

Comment: Good! But now how can I adjust this part of my header to get the size I want?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @LouisG.Talbot I wasn't sure if you made the changes on the "live site" - the one you provided us with. I now see that you did. I'll go check it out

Comment: Changes are made on the live site.

Comment: @LouisG.Talbot I actually don't even see the `sign in` button anymore

Comment: How about now, can you see it?

Comment: I'm not sure where you found "text-user" it seems like it is not part of my Html.

Comment: @LouisG.Talbot I *added* it to the `input` field - look at *my* html in the answer :)

Comment: I updated the CSS and HTML as per your recommendations but it's still shifting up.

Comment: The same problem occurs when I type in the password as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28318/discussion-between-evan-and-louis-g-talbot)

Answer (score 1):

Very strange bug, and I can't explain what's going on. But it is related to your `div.header-navigation.back`. If you remove that, the behaviour disappears.

As far as I can tell, you are only using that element for your background image, so it's not a good idea to include it in the markup anyway. If you amend your `.site-header` you can achieve the same effect without the extra `div`:

```
.site-header {
   background: #0894ff url('http://frenchegg.com/images/backmenu.png') 50% 20px no-repeat;
   background: url('http://frenchegg.com/images/backmenu.png') 50% 20px no-repeat,
               linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}
```

I couldn't quite work out what you're trying to achieve with your gradient, but the idea would be to provide multiple backgrounds for those browsers that support them, with a fallback to a solid colour.

Comment: I replaced my .site-header with the code you gave me. However in Chrome, the backmenu.png picture doesn't show up anymmore.

Comment: Later in your stylesheet (line 4142) you are re-declaring a `background-image`, which is over-riding it.

Comment: I only have 4119 lines, I can't find where it is.

Comment: Your stylesheet (3.5.1, [here](http://frenchegg.com/wp-content/themes/learnfrench/style.css?ver=3.5.1) has 4249 lines. The line in question has the selector `.jp-interface,
.widget-title,
.site-header,
.site-footer`

Comment: It works great! However, the site-header is now too small. What would be the best way to make it bigger? Adding a padding to it?

Comment: I added padding:1em; and it expanded my header. But there is another strange issue now. If you click on the "Password Recovery" button. The form to put in your email will appear. But when you click on it, the form goes back to the "Log in" form.

Answer (score 0):

You could give it a z-index instead of a fixed position, and give it an absolute position.